# Angular2 Routing - move from a child route to another child route which has different parent

Tags: angular

I have two parent routes Accounts and Account-Details.
Accounts have child route view, add, etc..and also Account-Details too have
child routes view,add etc.
Accounts -> view contains a list of accounts and when clicked on a account column,
i want to route to Acoount-Details->view with param(id).
How could can be done this
I tried

```
<tr *ngFor = "#item of data">
                <a  [routerLink]="['AccountDetailsView',{id:1}]"><td data-label="Account Name">{{ item.AccountName }}</td></a>
                <td data-label="Account Owner" class="smallHidden">{{ item.AccountOwner }}</td>
                <td data-label="Type" class="smallHidden">{{ item.Type }}</td>
                <td data-label="Tags" class="smallHidden">{{ item.Tags }}</td>
                <td data-label="Price" class="smallHidden">{{ item.Price }}</td>
                <td data-label="Actions" class="smallHidden">{{ item.Actions }}</td>
              </tr>
```

Error : no route named AccountDetailsView for component

Answer (score -1):

I solved it myself:

```
 <a  [routerLink]="['../AccountDetails/AccountDetailsView',{id:1}]">
```

We can trace the route structure.